# Identify building assets in-game

Tags: mods, cities-skylines

I recently subscribed to a bunch of building assets through the Steam workshop to give my city a little more variety. A couple of the buildings don't look that great in my city, though, so I'd like to remove just a few particular assets. Is there any easy way to find out, in-game, what is the asset name for a particular building? I'd like to find the building in my city, get the asset name, and then remove it from the asset list in the main menu.

Or do I have to go through my asset list one by one, looking for the offending building? Some of the thumbnail photos in the Steam workshop aren't that great, making it tough to identify from just the pictures. Is there any better way than opening the assets individually in the asset editor until I find the few that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regrettably, not really. Unique building assets will usually retain their name making them easier to search for and disable. However buildings that are generated for your R/C/I zones tend to have randomized names that do not reflect anything searchable in the assets list.

I have not been able to find any Workshop mod that would allow you to see the asset name when viewing a building. There *is* one called [Improved Assets Panel](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=449020940&searchtext=asset) which reconfigures that menu to reduce wasted space and view more assets at once, and allows you to filter assets based on their type (residential / commercial / industrial / prop / vehicle / etc). It isn't quite as convenient as directly searching for the specific asset name, but being able to filter by the asset's type (which you can see when it is selected in-game) will *drastically* improve the efficiency of finding the asset you are looking for.